# Display Partial in Modal with Foundation and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I am trying to create what I thought was a simple modal login window in rails using foundation. Unfortunately it isn't as easy I thought.

Basically what I am trying to do is provide a link to the user on the main page that when they click, will display the devise signup form in a modal window.

Can someone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything already? Code example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example of how you would do it foundation

```
<%= link_to "Sign Up", '#', data: {:'reveal-id' => 'signupModal'} %>
<div id="signupModal" class="reveal-modal">
    <%= render 'devise/registrations/new' %>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

You have to rename the `devise/registrations/new` to `devise/registrations/_new` to make it a partial.

You can find the full set of options and documentation in the [foundation docs on reveal](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html)

Answer (score 0):

Foundation Js Reveal also support ajax content part.

```
<a href="http://controller-action" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-reveal-ajax="true">new action link</a>
<a href="http://controller-action2" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-reveal-ajax="true">edit action link</a>
```

In controller-action , render ajax content with **layout: false**

```
def controller-action
  @xy = @x.y.new
  render :layout => false
end
```

In controller-action view, add your form and close button;

```
<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
<%= form_for(@xy, url: "/create-action", :method=>'post') do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name , placeholder: '....' %>
  <%=  f.submit 'Save', class: 'button tiny right', data: { disable_with: "wait..." } %>
<% end  %>
```